# JQuery Radio Button checked and change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In my ASP.NET MVC application there are two radio buttons and one combo box.

Someone clicked to radiobutton 1, combo box load some data. If clicked to the radiobutton 2, loads different data to the combo box. Script was written using the ajax.

The code is working fine when User click changed the radio buttons. But for some users I have hidden the radiobutton 2. So for them only radiobutton 1 is visible, But at that situation, there is no data loaded to the combo box.

Want to know that also, If there is radiobutton checked when load the view, need to get related data to the combobox.

```js
$(function() {

  $('[id*=ddlTopEmployees]').select2().next().hide();
  $('[id*=Approve_Type]').change(function() {
    setDropDownProductsA($(this).val())
  });
});

function setDropDownProductsA(xVal) {
  try {

    $("#ddlEmployees").empty().trigger("change")
    $.ajax({
      url: '../FindProductTypes',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      data: {
        AppLvlId: xVal
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.Success == true) {

          $("#ddlEmployees").select2({
            width: '100%',
            data: JSON.parse(data.items)
          });
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So trigger the load onload

Comment: @mplungjan tried onload. Not working

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and mock the ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use click instead of change

```
$('[id*=Approve_Type]').click(function() {
    setDropDownProductsA($(this).val())
  });
```